# Hybrid asp.net 4 and MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am in the process of migrating a asp.net 4 project to MVC 3 - with plans to migrate to MVC4 once everything had been migrated.  I followed this post:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntegratingASPNETMVC3IntoExistingUpgradedASPNET4WebFormsApplications.aspx

Created an Area, added the Controllers and Views folders, created a controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
    return View();
  }
}
```

Ran the application and checked the standard Aspx pages and then worked fine and then went to the path of the Controller and get the "Error: Value can not be null. Parameter name: incomingMarkupParser" error.  So, I then removed the return View(); and replaced it with return Content("Hello world"); and this worked with no problems at all.

So I thought to myself, is there a problem with the area... Created a Controllers and Views folder and tried again - same problem.

System.Web.Razor is version 2.0.0.0
System.Web.WebPages is version 1.0.0.0 (also tried version 2)

Web.Config

```
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  </assemblies>

  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
  </namespaces>
```

I know the problem is to do with Razor but I cannot find what.  Has anyone else experienced this, and if so how did they overcome it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you manually add the MVC references to web.config? As @PaulZhara said, there aren't any Razor references in your snippet. (Razor lives in its own assembly.)

Comment: No... I thought you didn't have to.  Looking at another MVC3 project (not hybrid) it isn't in there.  Do I need to add it as an assembly in my web.config file?

Comment: I've added it in and get a http error 500.19 it errors on <configSections> :(

Comment: You may try creating a new, default MVC Razor web app, and copying the web.config to your project. Also make sure the Razor assemblies are present when viewing your project in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Where are all your Razor references in the web.config? (I suspect this is the real issue) See [this page for an example](http://forums.asp.net/t/1663125.aspx/1)

You could also try [this link and the bit of code there](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/03/14/monitoring-asp-net-mvc-application.aspx) to see all exceptions (including those swallowed up)

Comment: The scott blog post you link to is all about building a hybrid mvc / asp.net application (sounds a bit messy for my liking), are you trying to build a hybrid app ? Personally I would prefer, if only for my own sanity to migrate an asp.net app to a seperate MVC project.

Comment: I used NuGet to go and get the packages for me:

Comment: PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Razor
You are downloading Microsoft.AspNet.Razor from Microsoft, the license agreement to which is available at .....

Comment: I then realised I would need the Mvc Package as well and got version 3: Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Version 3.0.20105.1

Answer (score 1):

Have you made sure you've got a web.config in your views folder? I believe that's where your razor config stuff goes. Or at least that's how I've got mine. Try looking at the Views > web.config for a new MVC project, that's where mine comes from.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I created a new project and moved everything across.  Thanks for your comment though

Comment: Ah, I was too late to save your hybrid. Damn. But that should do it if you run into it in future.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add or fix

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

to your web.config. This tells the runtime to use System.Web.Mvc Assembly for versions 1, 2, and 3.
Also, don't mix Razor engines, 2.0 is ASP.NET MVC 4. you need 1.0 for ASP.NET MVC 3. I think that could be your problem.